# I want to Disable default pageview event from GTM init loading

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Iam facing issue with google tag manager ,I want to Disable default pageview event from GTM 
this happening always when refreshing page (After form submit)

```
 (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
                w[l] = w[l] || [];
                w[l].push({
                    'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                    event: 'gtm.js'
                });
                var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    j = d.createElement(s),
                    dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
                j.async = true;
                j.src =
                    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
                f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXXX');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie and check its presence before sending the second pageview. Or with a variable after form has been sent and based on its presence you do not send the pageview.

Comment: im not sending any pageview it automatically sending to GTM like this "/" i want to stop that initial auto page view

Comment: GTM does nothing automatically. Probably your trigger executes the tag on all pages, you will have to create a rule (for example with the indications that I gave you in the answer above) where the tag is executed on all pages except for that condition.